# Javascript array is syncing with another assigned array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, copy

I've been racking my brain trying to figure out why these arrays are syncing after I assign one to the other. The output should be "1, 2, 3, 4" but instead it's "5, 6, 7, 8". Do I need to copy the arrays differently?

```
var firstArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var secondArray = [5, 6, 7, 8];

for (i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
  var myTempArray = firstArray; 
  myTempArray[i] = secondArray[i];
}
console.log("Result: " + firstArray);
```

Expected output:

```
Result: 1,2,3,4
```

Actual output:

```
Result: 5,6,7,8
```

How do I alter the second array without changing the first array?

Comment: your code is clearly altering the first array through myTempArray, and the code doesn't even attempt to alter the second array ever

Comment: `myTempArray` and `firstArray` both reference the same array. In JavaScript, objects (including arrays) are reference values.

Comment: var myTempArray = firstArray doesn't COPY the array ... it makes myTempArray reference the same data as is in firstArray - to make a (simple) copy of an array use array.slice ... i.e. `var myTempArray = firstArray.slice()` - this should be done BEFORE the loop

Comment: If you want to get fancy..  `var myTempArray = [...firstArray];` Using a Spread will create a copy, not a reference.

Comment: Added some new ideas, so reopened. `:D`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are mutable objects. So they just contain references. You need to "copy" an array in order to make a copy, not just assign like primitive objects. To copy an array, there are various methods. One best method is:

```
myTempArray = firstArray.slice();
```

What you are doing is a **shallow copy**:

[image]

Also, another big issue is that, you have the array assignment inside the loop, which keeps the `myTempArray` changing. You need to take it out of the loop. Your final code should look like:

```js
var firstArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var secondArray = [5, 6, 7, 8];

var myTempArray = firstArray.slice();
for (i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
  myTempArray[i] = secondArray[i];
}
console.log("Result: " + firstArray);
```

Comment: I moved the array declaration out of the loop and it a made no difference. The slice() ended the reference. Thanks